# Content in UIScrollView not scrolling

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, swift5

I have a UIScrollView in my UIViewController. I can scroll the ScrollView (I can see the bar at the bottom of the scrollView moving), but the content I put as a subView into the ScrollView is not moving. Anybody have an idea, what I am doing wrong?

This is my ScrollView:

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

This is how I call it in viewDidLoad():

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:2000, height: 5678)
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.anchor()
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .red

let priceLabelStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [price1Stack, price2Stack, price3Stack, price4Stack])
    priceLabelStack.axis = .horizontal
    priceLabelStack.spacing = 30

scrollView.addSubview(priceLabelStack)
    priceLabelStack.anchor(top: stack.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 30, paddingRight: 30)
    }
```

And this is the LayoutSubviews:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    scrollView.frame = view.bounds
}
```

So the content (priceLabelStack) is not moving..

Answer (score 0):

```
priceLabelStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        priceLabelStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        priceLabelStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        priceLabelStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        priceLabelStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

This was missing in my `viewDidLoad()`. Everything is working now